what do I do if my code is printing only one dictionary when i have several list after scraping a website using selenium
This is my code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url ='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXbTop77dnX35'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

songs = []

musics = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "IjYxRc5luMiDPhKhZVUH.UpiE7J6vPrJIa59qxts4")

for music in musics:
    title = music.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btE2c3IKaOXZ4VNAb8WQ").text
    album = music.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_TH6YAXEzJtzSxhkGSqu").text
    artist = music.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Text__TextElement-sc-if376j-0.gYdBJW.encore-text-             body-small").text
    duration = music.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "PAqIqZXvse_3h6sDVxU0").text
    print(title, album, artist, duration)

new_music = {
    'title' : title,
    'album' : album,
    'artist' : artist,
    'duration' : duration
}

songs.append(new_music)
print(songs)

And this is my result
{'title': 'Let It Flow', 'album': 'Let It Flow', 'artist': 'Maya Amolo', 'duration': '2:58'}

I want to create a dictionary for all the result i got but its printing just the last one

You should do the .append inside the for loop, otherwise it will only append once. Indent everything between those two print so they are inside the loop.

You're creating the new_music dictionary AFTER the loop has already finished, so of course it only has the final song from the loop.

Indent is important in python. It tells the compiler what is and is not in scope. You need to indent in from new_music = { down to the second to last line. print(songs) should not be indented so that it runs at the end.
Also, you are not using By.CLASS_NAME correctly. It expects a single class name and in some cases you are sending it a partial CSS selector. It works but it's purely by accident. By.CLASS_NAME passes the info to a CSS selector behind the scenes so that's why your partial CSS selectors are working. Instead change them to use By.CSS_SELECTOR.
The fixed code is below
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url ='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXbTop77dnX35'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

songs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".IjYxRc5luMiDPhKhZVUH.UpiE7J6vPrJIa59qxts4")
for song in songs:
    title = song.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btE2c3IKaOXZ4VNAb8WQ").text
    album = song.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_TH6YAXEzJtzSxhkGSqu").text
    artist = song.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Text__TextElement-sc-if376j-0.gYdBJW.encore-text-body-small").text
    duration = song.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "PAqIqZXvse_3h6sDVxU0").text
    print(title, album, artist, duration)

    new_music = {
        'title' : title,
        'album' : album,
        'artist' : artist,
        'duration' : duration
    }

    songs.append(new_music)

print(songs)

and it prints

[{'title': 'Adenuga (feat. Qing Madi)', 'album': 'Adenuga x Concerning', 'artist': 'Joeboy, Qing Madi', 'duration': '2:40'}, {'title': 'Wahala (feat. Olamide)', 'album': 'Wahala (feat. Olamide)', 'artist': 'CKay, Olamide', 'duration': '2:50'}, {'title': 'Fortnight (feat. Post Malone)', 'album': 'THE TORTURED POETS DEPARTMENT', 'artist': 'Taylor Swift, Post Malone', 'duration': '3:48'}, {'title': 'IN MY HEAD', 'album': 'IN MY HEAD', 'artist': 'Timaya, Tiwa Savage', 'duration': '2:57'}, ...

